# How to delete the ADFPipeline which is having the references Forcefully

Tags: azure, powershell, pipeline, azure-data-factory

I'm actually some automation for my ADF. As a part of that, I'm trying to delete all the ADF V2 pipelines. The problem is my pipelines having many references with different pipelines itself.

```
$ADFPipeline = Get-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -DataFactoryName $(datafactory-name) -ResourceGroupName $(rg)



$ADFPipeline | ForEach-Object { Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -ResourceGroupName $(rg) -DataFactoryName $(datafactory-name) -Name  $_.name -Force }
```

And most of the time I get the error like

> The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by "blabla"

I understand the error that it saying some references and cannot be deleted. However, when I tried the same deletion in the azure portal, irrespective of the reference I can able to delete. So I want to find a way that whether it possible to tell that Powershell even though it's having a reference delete it forcefully

Any other inputs much appreciated!

Comment: I don't think you can do that in the portal. Did you click the `Publish all` after clicking the `Delete` button in the portal? If not, you did not delete it successfully.

Comment: Do you have the PowerShell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello and thank you for the question.  According to [the Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/remove-azdatafactoryv2pipeline?view=azps-28..0), the `-Force` flag simply skips the confirmation prompt.  It does not actually 'Force' the deletion in spite of errors.

Since you are already doing automation, might I suggest leveraging the error message to recursively attempt to delete the referencing pipeline.  `$error[0]` gets the most recent error.

(Pseudocode)

```
try_recurse_delete( pipeline_name )
    do_delete(pipeline_name)
    if not $error[0].contains("referenced by " + pipeline_name)
        then return true
    else
        try_recurse_delete( get_refrencer_name($error[0]) )
```

Given that pipeline dependencies can be a many-to-many relationship, subsequent pipelines in your for-each loop might already be deleted by the recursion.  You will have to adapt your code to react to 'pipeline not found' type errors.

Comment: By any chance, so anyone have a working piece of code

Comment: @NareshKumar you could look at my answer above

Answer (score 4):

I run into the same issue, found out that it's rather complicated to build the whole dependency graph out of the pipeline's Activities property.

As a working solution (powershell):

```
function Remove-Pipelines {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [AllowEmptyCollection()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$pipelines
    )
    if($pipelines.Count -gt 0) {
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$plsToProcess = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
        foreach ($pipeline in $pipelines) { 
            try {
                $removeAzDFCommand = "Remove-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline -dataFactoryName '$DataFactoryName' -resourceGroupName '$ResourceGroupName' -Name '$($pipeline.Name)' -Force -ErrorAction Stop"
                Write-Host $removeAzDFCommand
                Invoke-Expression $removeAzDFCommand
            }
            catch {
                if ($_ -match '.*The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by.*') {
                    Write-Host $_
                    $plsToProcess.Add($pipeline)
                } else {
                    throw $_
                }
            }
        }
        Remove-Pipelines $plsToProcess
    }
}
```

Here is the complete solution for clearing the whole DF: "trigger","pipeline","dataflow","dataset","linkedService"

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $ResourceGroupName,
  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string] $DataFactoryName
)

$artfTypes = "trigger","pipeline","dataflow","dataset","linkedService"

function Remove-Artifacts {
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][AllowEmptyCollection()][AllowNull()][System.Collections.ArrayList]$artifacts,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$artfType
    )
    if($artifacts.Count -gt 0) {
        [System.Collections.ArrayList]$artToProcess = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList($null)
        foreach ($artifact in $artifacts) { 
            try {
                $removeAzDFCommand = "Remove-AzDataFactoryV2$($artfType) -dataFactoryName '$DataFactoryName' -resourceGroupName '$ResourceGroupName' -Name '$($artifact.Name)' -Force -ErrorAction Stop"
                Write-Host $removeAzDFCommand
                Invoke-Expression $removeAzDFCommand
            }
            catch {
                if ($_ -match '.*The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by.*') {
                    Write-Host $_
                    $artToProcess.Add($artifact)
                } else {
                    throw $_
                }
            }
        }
        Remove-Artifacts $artToProcess $artfType
    }
}

foreach ($artfType in $artfTypes) {
  $getAzDFCommand = "Get-AzDataFactoryV2$($artfType) -dataFactoryName '$DataFactoryName' -resourceGroupName '$ResourceGroupName'"
  Write-Output $getAzDFCommand

  $artifacts = Invoke-Expression $getAzDFCommand
  Write-Output $artifacts.Name

  Remove-Artifacts $artifacts $artfType
}
```

The same approach can be adapted for `"Set-AzDataFactoryV2Pipeline"` command as well.

It worth to mention that along with dependencies tracking, Remove/Set artifact's sequence should be right (because of cross artifacts' dependencies).

For Set - `"linkedService","dataset","dataflow","pipeline","trigger"`

For Remove - `"trigger","pipeline","dataflow","dataset","linkedService"`