# Azure ADF - What should be the order of deleting different components

Tags: azure

I am writing the powershell script for some cleanup activity and wanted to know what should be the order of deleting different component. I have written following function, but not sure in which order should I execute them.

1. Disable-Triggers
2. Delete-Pipelines
3. Delete-Triggers
4. Delete-DataSets
5. Delete-LinkedServices
6. Delete-IntegrationRuntimes

Answer (score 0):

Your order of execution is correct. This way you can escape from the dependency.

Also, note if you have multiple pipelines which having the reference you have a workaround for that also

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58635336/7073340)

Comment: in my case, one pipeline calls multiple pipeline and so it fails. would executing same command multiple times will resolve this issue ?

Comment: for these kinds of reference issue, i provided the answer in the [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58635336/7073340), as per that you need recursively attempt to delete the referencing pipeline